# Correct use for avoiding unnecessary casts with generic types (SuppressWarnings unchecked conversion)

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

There are similar questions out there but I didn't find any that really answers my concerns or that covers my actual implementation.

With the following example code (which reflects my actual situation)

```
public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WhateverDtoXmlParser parser = (new MainTest()).new WhateverDtoXmlParser();

        // I want to do this (having to do suppressWarnings)
        WhateverDto wd = parser.getDto();

        // Instead of (usage without the warning).
        // I want to avoid all of this!
        Dto d = parser.getDto();
        WhateverDto wd2 = null;
        if (d instanceof WhateverDto) { // All of this is stupid and unnecessary IMO.
            wd2 = (WhateverDto) d;
        }
    }

    abstract class AbstractDtoXmlParser {
        public abstract <T extends Dto> T getDto();
    }

    class WhateverDtoXmlParser extends AbstractDtoXmlParser {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public WhateverDto getDto() { // instead of public Dto getDto() (to avoid instanceof + cast)
            return new WhateverDto();
        }
    }

    abstract class Dto {
        // ...
    }

    public class WhateverDto extends Dto {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Would you consider this a correct usage even though I used a suppresswarnings?
I mean I **KNOW** the returned type from `WhateverDtoXmlParser` will be a `WhateverDto` and not just any other Dto because **I coded it that way**. Why can't Java check if the return type `extends Dto` **as I explicitly specified it with `<T extends Dto`>** (plus it extends an abstract class...) and accept it?

It's either I do this there, OR I have to use `instanceof`s and casts everytime I use `getDto()` .. ! It seems to me that my current implementation is the "best" but then why do I get such a concerning warning?

After reading the other threads it seems that there is no way to get around this warning, but should I go on with my current implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
abstract class AbstractDtoXmlParser<T extends Dto> {
    public abstract T getDto();
}

class WhateverDtoXmlParser extends AbstractDtoXmlParser<WhateverDto> {

    @Override
    public WhateverDto getDto() {
        return new WhateverDto();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow I think that'll do the job and it seems to me that this is the "best" way.
Why didn't I think of this? I kinda feel stupid now but hey, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you know for sure the type you are getting back is the type you are expecting, there is nothing wrong with doing an unsafe cast like this...

```
WhateverDto d = (WhateverDto) parser.getDto();
```

This still isn't the cleanest but it shouldn't give you warnings and it won't take 4 lines to write either.

Comment: Well yeah that's what I thought in the first place but I wanted to get some feedback on if it's not a bad practice, so thanks!

But I think I'll use Dilum's answer since it matched my case perfectly.

Comment: Yes, Dilum's answer would be better to use if you control the interface or abstract class which is being used so that you may change it's API. If the class is in a 3rd party framework, but you still know for sure what type it returns, my answer will work best .